# choosing odd number of balls from $n$ balls

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can an odd number of balls be chosen from $n$ balls?

I tried enumerating, but it's really too tedious. :/ Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are the balls identical, or totally different, or somewhere in between?

Comment: I think it's distinct

Comment: @freak_warrior is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: #ways of choosing even balls = #ways of choosing odd balls.

and total number of ways of choosing balls = $2^n$ (Why?)

Comment: I think I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Not if $n$ is 0 :)